# Linear Combinations of Least Square Estimator

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

I come across a problem about finding the least square estimator of A$\beta$, where $\beta$ is the parameter vector in linear model ($Y=X\beta+\epsilon$). My question is, would the least square estimator of A$\beta$ be Ab, where b is the least square estimator of $\beta$? 
I know that Ab is BLUE (best linear unbiased estimator) of A$\beta$, but I'm not sure if this property guarantees it to be the least square estimator of A$\beta$. Can you guys help me prove/disprove it? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ to be an invertible matrix of constants, Let $\gamma = A\beta$ then for the model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon = XA^{-1}\gamma + \epsilon$. Hence $\hat{\gamma} = ({A'}^{-1}X'XA^{-1})^{-1}A'^{-1}X'Y = A(X'X)^{-1}(A'A'^{-1})X'Y = A(X'X)^{-1}X'Y = A\hat{\beta}$

Hence this will be true under all non-singular transformations.

Comment: The problem here is A is not necessarily a square matrix and as I stated, I'm particularly looking at the linear combination, which means A is a row vector.